# How to use .ToLower() properly in this case?

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison, tolower

So what I'm attempting to do is have this program ignore a user's letter case when entered. I see how to use `.ToLower()`; however I'm not understanding how to do this the right way.

Here's what I have now, am I close? I've read a bunch of tutorials online however they are mostly just standalone programs that convert user input to lower. Is there a way to enable this globally?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Choose_Your_Color
{
class Program
{
    enum Color
    {
        red,
        orange,
        blue,
        black,
        white,
        green,
        purple,
        yellow
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Color favorite;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What color do you choose?");
            if (Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out favorite))
                if (string.compare(favorite , Enum , true) == 0){
                    Continue;
                }



            {
                switch (favorite)
                {
                    case Color.red:
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose red!");
                        break;
                    case Color.orange:
                        Console.WriteLine("you chose orange!!!!!!");
                        break;
                    case Color.blue:
                        Console.WriteLine("YOU CHOSE BLUEEEE!!");
                        break;
                    case Color.black:
                        Console.WriteLine("you chose black");
                        break;
                    case Color.white:
                        Console.WriteLine(" you chose white!");
                        break;
                    case Color.green:
                        Console.WriteLine("you chose green!!!!!");
                        break;
                    case Color.purple:
                        Console.WriteLine("you chose purple!!");
                        break;
                    case Color.yellow:
                        Console.WriteLine("you chose yellow!!!");
                        break;

                }
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That's not a color!");
            }





        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Just change this;

```
if (Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out favorite))
```

to

```
if (Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToLower(), out favorite))
```

Console.ReadLine() returns a string, this will call to lower on that value ensuring that all the input is lower cased.

Why do you have this line?

```
            if (string.compare(favorite , Enum , true) == 0){
                Continue;
            }
```

I don't think there is any reason for it. `Enum.TryParse` should either return false meaning the input wasn't one of the enums and you won't go into the switch statement OR `favorite` will be one of the enum values and you'll go into one of the cases in your switch statement.

Comment: Hmmm, It still returns it as it not being recognized.

Comment: Is this because of the while loop its in?

Comment: @user3554677 perhaps the input doesn't match any of the enum values? You might also want to call `Trim()` on the input as it could have whitespaces which would prevent a match. Also, one last thing I'll edit into my answer.

Comment: I removed the second if statement. The code is exactly as the way it was minus the second if statement and the addition of "if (Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToLower(), out favorite))"

Comment: @user3554677 with that being the case you code is very similar to the examples on msdn. Can you set a break point in the body of the if and see what's happening? The use of `Enum.TryParse` is correct so I'm not sure what would be causing the problem.

Comment: Ok sorry about that. For some reason, my compiler wasn't updating the source code for the build when I went to compile it. VS 2013 is a bit buggy =P

Comment: Yes, works flawlessly. Thank you for the help! Is there a guide of reference manual that contains information about functions and their accepted arguments? I'm new to this so i didn't even realize you can just tack on arguments to things like that.

Comment: @user3554677 everything in .NET is pretty well documented by Microsoft. If you search "enum C# .net msdn" the top result will be the docs for the type. You can also search the method names to get directly to say `TryParse` here's a link for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Enum(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user3554677 ps if my answer worked for you accept it :p

Answer (score 3):

You just need to do:

```
if (Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToLower(), out favorite))
```

You don't need that nested `if`, you can just remove it.Also you have to add a break to the end of your if block, so it will break your loop after user type a valid value otherwise the loop will never end.

Answer (score 3):

`Enum.TryParse` accepts a parameter to ignore case:

```
Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), true, out favorite);
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `TryParse` allows you to ignore the case of the input string, so you could just write this as:

```
if (Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), true, out favorite))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`String.ToLower()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower.aspx) will return the string value as lowercase.

```
if (Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToLower(), out favorite))
```